# Using DbLinq in IronPython

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq, ironpython, dblinq

I'm trying to use [dblinq](http://dblinq.codeplex.com/) in my IronPython application but am having some problems getting started. When trying to import dblinq classes,using clr.AddReference() it does not seem to see dblinq.

I can build but not access the library

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("DbLinq")
clr.AddReference("System.Data.Linq")
from System.Data.Linq import DataContext

exit = raw_input("press any key to quit")
```

1:
My dblinq source is in a subfolder called Resources

`clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("Resources/DbLinq.dll")`   => file not found

`clr.AddReference("DbLinq")`  => could not add reference to dblinq

`clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("C:/Development/DBLinq2/Dblinq.dll"`  => success

but still cannot use the classes  using `from DbLinq import ...`

#### Solution

```
    import clr

   clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("%s\Resources\DbLinq.dll" %os.getcwd())
    clr.AddReference("DbLinq")
    from Npgsql import *
    from DbLinq import Data
```

Comment: Maybe you are missing some other dependencies. Try running `Dependency Walker` (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on DbLinq.dll to see if that yields something interesting...

Comment: Hmm, IESHIMS.dll is one of the dependencies which you should not worry about... Did you run dependency walker on `Resources/DbLinq.dll` (you should) or `C:\Development\DBLinq2...` (that directory might contain other dll's which are needed in the `Resource` directory)

Comment: Did it on both, Resources contains all the files that Development\Dblinq2 does

Comment: so are you not able to use/import stock dblinq types or code from you based on that?
Have you tried adding your dblinq directory to the path?
`import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Temp\DbLinq-0.20.1")`

Comment: @Simon that doesn't work either

Comment: could you extend your question by adding the parts where you are using dblinq? I tried `from DbLinq.Data.Linq import Table` which worked ..

Comment: @Simon will post my full code above

Comment: you appended the dblinq.dll itself to the path .. could you try that again pointing to the folder containing all the dlls coming with dblinq? and you still need to `clr.AddReference("DbLinq")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For libraries like DbLinq that come with dependencies or are split into several DLLs/modules you can programmatically add their location to allow the runtime to find all required files.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Temp\DbLinq-0.20.1")
```

You can then reference all required assemblies as usual:

```
clr.AddReference("DbLinq")
```

If there is one primary assembly you can also use clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath (with an absolute path) which will implicitly add the referenced assemblies location to the path.

```
clr.AddReference(r"C:\Temp\DbLinq-0.20.1\DbLinq.dll")
```